# Can we pass values to a running GCP Cloud Composer Pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-composer

If I have a Dataproc workflow template scheduled using a Cloud Composer, Can I pass values to my dataproc jobs that are present inside Workflow Template through the Cloud Composer environment?
If yes please mention the source.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Do you need to pass parameter to running jobs in Dataproc or before every run in Composer? Are the values constant or changing over time?

Comment: Hi 
I need to pass parameters from composer to a running dataproc workflow and the values might change over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [DataprocInstantiateWorkflowTemplateOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/500780651cfef9254d5e365c0de6f8c7af6d05bf/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py#L1708) operator then you can use `parameters` [argument](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/500780651cfef9254d5e365c0de6f8c7af6d05bf/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py#L1724-L1728) which is "a map of parameters for Dataproc Template".

The fact that the `parameters` argument is one of templated fields means it can be configured using for example:

- DAG run configuration via [macros](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html) (using `{{ dag_run.conf }}`)
- [Airflow variables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/variable.html) (using for example `{{ var.value.get('my.var', 'fallback') }}`)
- Environment variables (`os.environ.get`)

You can also hardcode this `parameters` if you don't need option to change them from time to time.

Comment: What if I am using a .py file to run a pyspark job,
How do hold places inside that file to get input at runtime

Comment: Suppose I have a pyspark job that hits an API and writes some tables to big query but I am getting a lot of tables and I want to write only some of them to BQ

Comment: I'm not an expert in Dataproc so I would recommend checking this documentation on [parametrising workflows](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/workflows/workflow-parameters) especially I think job argument's may serve the purpose.

Comment: I tried job arguments but the major problem is even if I am able to pass some arguments say TABLE_NAME  as a parameter while I am instantiating my workflow template I am not able to call that parameter inside my,py file where my actual pyspark job is written and where I actually require that parameter.

Comment: From this [example](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/python-configuration) my understanding is that you can reference job argument using `sys.argv`, won't that help you?